# Acces legacy class from twig view

Tags: php, symfony, twig

We are re-writing part of a web portal and I need to do a bitwise compare in a twig view. I have the value(integer) in my view that is passed from the controller and I need to make a decision on what image to display. I used to just do a bitwise compare against values in a class that is somewhere in /opt folder.

I can do the bitwise (b-and) compare in twig but how do I get access to the legacy php class to do the comparison?

Comment: Would writing a twig extension and creating your own bitwise function help? From the extension class (regular PHP) you can include/require your legacy code.

Comment: My issue was not writing the bit wise compare function, it was getting access to the legacy class where constants were declared. I do not want to re-declare a cache-duration constant as an example if it already declared in that legacy class.

Comment: My point is, from within twig you cannot include a PHP class, you need to step out of the template, back into regular PHP code. The only way to do that is by calling a function from within twig (your own custom function and extension). From there you can include your class, access it's values then return to twig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a twig template you don't have access to regular PHP methods. So, to include your legacy class, you will need to write a custom function and twig extension. Here is an example:

```
class StepOutExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'inspect' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'step_out', array('needs_context' => true))
        );
    }
    public function stepOut($context)
    {
        // access your class here
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'legacy_class';
    }
}
```

And register the service:

```
services:
    my_namespace.step_out:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Extensions\StepOutExtension
        tags:
          - { name: twig.extension }
```

within twig you can call your new function

```
{{ step_out() }}
```

More details can be found [in the Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

Comment: Thanks @Twifty I worked on this today and was able to make it work with your answer. I did not go with this solution however, I opted to add a getter to my entity and just called that from the view - it made the view a lot cleaner. Thanks.

Comment: @JackSmit Happy to help. If you had mentioned passing an object to your template, the solution would have been much easier :p

Answer (score 0):

You can access to class constant via twig with the [constant function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html#constant) as follow:

```
{{ constant('Namespace\\Classname::CONSTANT_NAME') }}
```

You can access to constant to class instance also as:

```
{{ constant('RSS', date) }}
```

You can compare a value with a standard if statement or with the [constant test](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/constant.html#constant) (that  checks if a variable has the exact same value as a constant) as follow:

```
{% if post.status is constant('Post::PUBLISHED') %}
    the status attribute is exactly the same as Post::PUBLISHED
{% endif %}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Sorry Matteo, this did not work. My app is running in /var/www/mysite and the class is in /opt/services so there must be some way for me to include that class file in the twig or I will not be able to see it, correct>?

Comment: Hi @JackSmit so you the class is not in your autoloader path? Ho do you include this?